# j2ee spring mvc best practice for small application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working with small app that uses spring-hibernate but I am a newcomer to field of spring MVC, I have some questions:

1) using single controller for multiple pages is good practice or should I create separate cont. class for each page.

2) I don't want to use form tag of spring I'm using html forms.

My controller is as follows:

```
package com.servlets.controllers;

import com.utils.generalUtils;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class signin{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})  
    public ModelAndView loginForm(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse response){  
        HashMap<String,String> lsMsg = new HashMap<String,String>();

            lsMsg = generalUtils.getInstance().LoginCheck(req);
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : lsMsg.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                String value = entry.getValue();
                System.out.println("  key -- "+key+"  value -- "+value);
            }
            if((lsMsg.get("Authorized")).equals("true")){
                return new ModelAndView("landing", "message", lsMsg);
            }
            return new ModelAndView("login", "message", lsMsg);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/fergot", method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})  
    public ModelAndView fergotForm(HttpServletRequest req) {  // Not implemented yet
            HashMap<String,String> lsMsg = new HashMap<String,String>();
            return new ModelAndView("fergot", "message", lsMsg);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/register")  
    public ModelAndView registerForm(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{  
        HashMap<String,String> lsMsgs = new HashMap<String,String>();
        lsMsgs.put("Authorized", "false");
            lsMsgs = generalUtils.getInstance().addUser(req);
            if((lsMsgs.get("Authorized")).equals("true")){
                response.sendRedirect("login.html");
            }
            return new ModelAndView("register", "message", lsMsgs);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Both way are ok. But you want best practise, so my suggestion is create separate controller class for each page . This is common choice in most cases. On the other hand, if your app is very very small, even if you using single controller is also not a big problem.

Chose which way's core problem is which way can maintain easier in the future and which way is more readable for others.

2) You say you don't want to use spring form tag, ofcourse you can. Take it easy, You can not use any part of spring you don't want to use, it is ok.